# Minicom black background color is not respected

Tags: linux, terminal, xterm

If I start minicom in a terminal using color with the option "-c on", black background is actually grey.

```
minicom -c on
```

If I setup any color in the settings, such as red, the background color is respected

```
minicom -c on -s
#Go to "Screen and keyboard", change "Background Color (term)"
```

But black is definitely grey. Any idea why is that?

Comment: this sounds like question for [linux.se]

Comment: Yes and no. I have read the code and I suspect a bug in minicom-2.7/src/window.c. I should post on the minicom maling list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Black will be "gray" on some terminals, not others, due to differences in color palettes.  Minicom is using the curses support for eight ANSI colors.  There is no standard for the *actual* colors used.  "ANSI" (actually ECMA-48) only gives the *names* of the colors, for given *numbers*.

Users of both gnome-terminal and konsole have noticed that their "black" background is actually *gray*.  Apparently their developers did this to make the terminal look *nicer* on the desktop; no consideration was made for actually *using* the terminal. xterm and rxvt use *black* (or *white*, depending on resource settings).  For the former, you can usually edit your profile preferences and change the palette color assignments.

Here are sample screenshots from my Debian 7 machine to illustrate the differences you may see:

First, xterm

[image: screenshot of xterm]

then gnome-terminal

[image: screenshot of gnome-terminal]

and konsole:

[image: screenshot of konsole]

Further reading:

- [Can I set a color by its number?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#color_by_number)
- [I don't like that shade of blue](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#dont_like_blue)
- [ECMA-48: Control Functions for Coded Character Sets](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)

But that is only part of the story.  Minicom was originally written to be specific to the Linux console.  Those terminals can display 8 foreground and 8 background colors.  But they do something interesting with the *bold* attribute:

- a bold foreground color is brighter
- a bold background also may be brighter.

The source-code isn't particularly sophisticated, and it draws colors and attributes (such as bold) assuming that they are independent of each other.  It does not use ncurses.  If it did, it (via ncurses) would pay attention to the `ncv` capability.  Quoting from [terminfo(5)](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html):

```
   no_color_video                ncv        NC        video attributes
                                                      that cannot be used 
                                                      with colors
```

and

```
   On  some color terminals, colors collide with highlights.  You can reg‐
   ister these collisions with the ncv capability.  This is a bit-mask  of
   attributes  not to be used when colors are enabled.  The correspondence
   with the attributes understood by curses is as follows:

                Attribute                   Bit    Decimal
                A_STANDOUT                  0     1
                A_UNDERLINE                 1     2  
                A_REVERSE                   2     4
                A_BLINK                     3     8
                A_DIM                       4     16  
                A_BOLD                      5     32
                A_INVIS                     6     64
                A_PROTECT                   7     128  
                A_ALTCHARSET                8     256

   For example, on many IBM PC consoles, the underline attribute  collides  
   with  the  foreground  color  blue  and is not available in color mode.
   These should have an ncv capability of 2.
```

If you use `infocmp` to see, the "linux" terminal description uses `ncv`:

```
linux|linux console,
        am, bce, ccc, eo, mir, msgr, xenl, xon,
        colors#8, it#8, ncv#18, pairs#64,
```

which is (again) part of the story (you may notice bold is not encoded in `ncv` here).  ncurses ***also*** orders the updates to the screen to keep from accidentally making a bold background — to handle the Linux console properly.

Comment: Bottom-line, if you want to fix the grey to black, change the color palette in your default terminal settings.