# curses not displaying color-pairs properly

Tags: python, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I am trying to understand how curses work, so I crafted an small piece of code to help me understand that. It's kind of messy, but it should get work fine (in theory). In the first file I defined every color-pair by hand, then I simply create an instance with each on the main file.

**`ANSICOLORS.PY`**

```
import curses

LGREY_LGREY = None
WHITE_LGREY = None
LGREY_WHITE = None
WHITE_WHITE = None
LGREY_BLACK = None
WHITE_BLACK = None
LGREY_DGREY = None
WHITE_DGREY = None
BLACK_LGREY = None
DGREY_LGREY = None
BLACK_WHITE = None
DGREY_WHITE = None
BLACK_BLACK = None
DGREY_BLACK = None
BLACK_DGREY = None
DGREY_DGREY = None

def delayed_init():
    global LGREY_LGREY, WHITE_LGREY, LGREY_WHITE, WHITE_WHITE, LGREY_BLACK, WHITE_BLACK, LGREY_DGREY, WHITE_DGREY \
        , BLACK_LGREY, DGREY_LGREY, BLACK_WHITE, DGREY_WHITE, BLACK_BLACK, DGREY_BLACK, BLACK_DGREY, DGREY_DGREY

    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
    curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
    curses.init_pair(3, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
    curses.init_pair(4, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
    curses.init_pair(5, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(6, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(7, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(8, curses.COLOR_WHITE, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(9, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
    curses.init_pair(10, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
    curses.init_pair(11, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
    curses.init_pair(12, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
    curses.init_pair(13, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(14, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(15, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(16, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_BLACK)


    LGREY_LGREY = curses.color_pair(1)
    WHITE_LGREY = curses.color_pair(2) | curses.A_BOLD
    LGREY_WHITE = curses.color_pair(3) | curses.A_REVERSE #CHECK
    WHITE_WHITE = curses.color_pair(4) | curses.A_BOLD | curses.A_REVERSE #CHECK

    LGREY_BLACK = curses.color_pair(5)
    WHITE_BLACK = curses.color_pair(6) | curses.A_BOLD
    LGREY_DGREY = curses.color_pair(7) | curses.A_REVERSE #CHECK
    WHITE_DGREY = curses.color_pair(8) | curses.A_BOLD | curses.A_REVERSE #CHECK

    BLACK_LGREY = curses.color_pair(9)
    DGREY_LGREY = curses.color_pair(10) | curses.A_BOLD
    BLACK_WHITE = curses.color_pair(11) | curses.A_REVERSE #CHECK
    DGREY_WHITE = curses.color_pair(12) | curses.A_BOLD | curses.A_REVERSE #CHECK

    BLACK_BLACK = curses.color_pair(13)
    DGREY_BLACK = curses.color_pair(14) | curses.A_BOLD
    BLACK_DGREY = curses.color_pair(15) | curses.A_REVERSE #CHECK
    DGREY_DGREY = curses.color_pair(16) | curses.A_BOLD | curses.A_REVERSE #CHECK
```

**`main.py`**

```
import curses
import time

import ANSICOLORS

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.start_color()
curses.use_default_colors()
ANSICOLORS.delayed_init()

colors = [  ANSICOLORS.LGREY_LGREY, ANSICOLORS.WHITE_LGREY, ANSICOLORS.LGREY_WHITE, ANSICOLORS.WHITE_WHITE, ANSICOLORS.LGREY_BLACK, ANSICOLORS.WHITE_BLACK, ANSICOLORS.LGREY_DGREY, ANSICOLORS.WHITE_DGREY,
            ANSICOLORS.BLACK_LGREY, ANSICOLORS.DGREY_LGREY, ANSICOLORS.BLACK_WHITE, ANSICOLORS.DGREY_WHITE, ANSICOLORS.BLACK_BLACK, ANSICOLORS.DGREY_BLACK, ANSICOLORS.BLACK_DGREY, ANSICOLORS.DGREY_DGREY]

win = curses.newwin(5, 50,1,1)

for y in range(4):
    for x in range(4):
        print(y*4 + x)
        win.addstr(y, x*5, f"▀█{y}█▀", colors[y*4 + x])

while True:
    win.refresh()
    time.sleep(1)
```

However, in practice I do not get every combination possible. Only `WHITE_LGREY` produces the color `WHITE`. For example, `WHITE_WHITE` produces a light grey image instead.

Here's the result:

[image: screenshot]

Even if my understanding of how the `BOLD` and `REVERSE` worked was wrong, I tried all 16 combinations of 'ON/OFF' with black and white, so in theory I should be getting a case of all instances.
Any ideas of what the problem could be? Am I missing some component of curses?

Comment: I'm no curses expert, but maybe the problem is simply that your terminal (emulator) doesn't support every possible combination.

Comment: This is one of several duplicates: [Minicom black background color is not respected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277542/minicom-black-background-color-is-not-respected)